# PostgreSQL query: obtain concise string of numbers

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

Obtain a concise string of the numbers, for example, given 1,2,3,6,7,8,9,12,14, we expect 1-3,6-9,12,14.

Here is the Table:

```
create table tt8 (c1 numeric);
insert into tt8 values
(1),(2),(3),(6),(7),(8),(9),(12),(14);
```

Use Table tt8, Here is what the result should look like:

```
numbers
---------------
1-3,6-9,12,14
```

Here is what I have so far, but it's giving me type error.
I don't think this is the correct way.

```
select c1,
case
when c1 = 1|2|3 then '1-3'
when c1 = 6|7|8|9 then '6-9'
else c1
end
from tt8;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a gaps-and-islands approach and then aggregation.  The following gets the groups:

```
select min(c1) || (case when count(*) = 1 then '' else '-' || max(c1) end)
from (select tt8.*, row_number() over (order by c1) as seqnum
      from tt8
     ) t
group by (c1 - seqnum);
```

You can then put them into a single string:

```
select string_agg(val, ',' order by min_c1)
from (select min(c1) || (case when count(*) = 1 then '' else '-' || max(c1) end) as val, min(c1) as min_c1
      from (select tt8.*, row_number() over (order by c1) as seqnum
            from tt8
           ) t
      group by (c1 - seqnum)
     ) t;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=dced772fd103d8ce455c33d2c1612b98) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: This is not working for me, I get errors in postgreSQL

Comment: @JackDaniels95 . . . I fixed the typos and added a fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

Please give this a try:

```
with trans as (
  select c1, 
         case when lag(c1) over (order by c1) = c1 - 1 then 0 else 1 end as new
    from tt8
), groups as (
  select c1, sum(new) over (order by c1) as grpnum
    from trans
), ranges as (
  select grpnum, min(c1) as low, max(c1) as high
    from groups
   group by grpnum
), texts as (
  select grpnum, 
         case 
           when low = high then low::text 
           else low::text||'-'||high::text
         end as txt
    from ranges
)
select string_agg(txt, ',' order by grpnum) as answer
  from texts;

    answer     
---------------
 1-3,6-9,12,14
(1 row)
```

You can change the last query to bring back the results of each CTE to see what is happening.

`trans` uses the `lag()` window function to mark rows that start groups:

```
 c1 | new 
----+-----
  1 |   1
  2 |   0
  3 |   0
  6 |   1
  7 |   0
  8 |   0
  9 |   0
 12 |   1
 14 |   1
(9 rows)
```

`groups` uses the `sum()` window function with the implicit `unbounded preceding` to assign each row a `grpnum`:

```
 c1 | grpnum 
----+--------
  1 |      1
  2 |      1
  3 |      1
  6 |      2
  7 |      2
  8 |      2
  9 |      2
 12 |      3
 14 |      4
(9 rows)
```

`ranges` collapses each `groupnum` to its `min()` and `max()`:

```
 grpnum | low | high 
--------+-----+------
      3 |  12 |   12
      4 |  14 |   14
      2 |   6 |    9
      1 |   1 |    3
(4 rows)
```

`texts` translates the `low` and `high` ranges into text representations:

```
 grpnum | txt 
--------+-----
      3 | 12
      4 | 14
      2 | 6-9
      1 | 1-3
(4 rows)
```

The `string_agg()` turns the `txt` values into a comma-separated list.